# Symfony: Special routing for mobile browsers

Tags: routes, symfony1, mobile-website

Is there any way that I can detect browser type on routing and use specific controller? I want to be able to do something like this in routing.yml:

```
mobile:
  url:   /*
  requirements:
    browser: mobile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This symfony blog article](http://www.symfony-project.org/blog/2008/06/09/how-to-create-an-optimized-version-of-your-website-for-the-iphone-in-symfony-1-1) from Fabien describes an elegant solution for an iPhone-optimised version of your website. Change the regexp he uses to something that more broadly matches the browsers/clients used to access your site, and you have a 'mobile' version.

EDIT: I would add that perhaps a different 'app' altogether might be a better solution, a la Facebook's [m.facebook.com](http://m.facebook.com/) interface.

Comment: Any updates for Symfony 2.5 ? The symfony blog article is for version 1.1 .

Answer (score 0):

Not really quite what you are after, but you could use the scripts from http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/ to detect what type of browser a request is coming from. You might they be able to integrate these scripts into a base controller (or router) class to handle requests appropriately.